# How to sleep imac os x 10.6.2?

Tags: macos, sleep, mac

I have my imac set to sleep after half an hour and often manually choose sleep.  It rarely ever stays sleeping.  It is becoming problematic because I work with a large volume of files a day and would like to keep my current state active for the next day.  I am not running any active processes such as ftp, dvds, music, etc.  Just simply have saved files open.

While I have printers installed on this computer, as well as the bluetooth mouse that comes with it, I am really baffled that there isn't a better solution than logging out (and thus killing my current session).  If this works on linux it should really work here.

Can someone please help me without a lecture about how this is "good" behavior?

Comment: So what happens? It sleeps after 30 minutes but then automatically wakes up soon afterwards?

Comment: Also, does the Console log (Applications -> Utilities -> Console) contain anything with the word "sleep" or "wake"? You might see something like "USB caused wake event".

Answer (score 2):

The following article from apple covers many possibilities:

- [Mac OS X: Why your Mac might not sleep or stay in sleep mode](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1776) (I know it is says upto 10.5 but may still apply.

*One of them being a bluetooth mouse.*

Another article for 10.6:

- [If your Mac computer won’t go to sleep or stay in sleep](http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?path=Mac/10.6/en/9040.html)